# As I can detect various function blocks with braces "{}" using regex?

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to extract the following text block functions only.

Example:

**// Comment 1. function example1() { return 1; } // Comment 2 function example2() { if (a < b) { a++ } } // Comment 3 function example3() { while (1) { i++; } } /* Comment 4 */ function example4() { i = 4; for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {  i++; } return i; }**

Take into account that no line breaks. It is a single block of code.

I have tried using the following regular expression:

Expression:

**function\s[a-z|A-Z|0-9_]+()\s?{(?:.+)\s}**

But there is a problem, place the .+ , take me all characters to the end of the text block.

Thanks in advance guys for the help you can give me.

Comment: Use `[^\}]+` instead of `.+`, it means "not curly closing bracket', and match anything but not `}`

Comment: What is the regex flavor? Is it .NET or PCRE?

Comment: This is in PCRE regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PCRE (PHP, R, Delphi), you can achieve this with recursion:

```
function\s[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\(\)(\s?{(?>[^{}]|(?1))*})
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aO7mL4/1).

In Ryby, just use `\g<1>` instead of `(?1)`:

```
function\s[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\(\)(\s?{(?>[^{}]|(\g<1>))*})
```

In .NET, you can match them using balanced groups:

```
function\s[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\(\)\s*{((?<sq>{)|(?<-sq>})|[^{}]*)+}
```

See [demo 2](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=function%5Cs%5Ba-zA-Z0-9_%5D%2B%5C(%5C)%5Cs*%7B((%3F%3Csq%3E%7B)%7C(%3F%3C-sq%3E%7D)%7C%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D*)%2B%7D&i=%2F%2F%20Comment%201.%20function%20example1()%20%7B%20return%201%3B%20%7D%20%2F%2F%20Comment%202%20function%20example2()%20%7B%20if%20(a%20%3C%20b)%20%7B%20a%2B%2B%20%7D%20%7D%20%2F%2F%20Comment%203%20function%20example3()%20%7B%20while%20(1)%20%7B%20i%2B%2B%3B%20%7D%20%7D%20%2F*%20Comment%204%20*%2F%20function%20example4()%20%7B%20i%20%3D%204%3B%20for%20(i%20%3D%201%3B%20i%20%3C%2010%3B%20i%2B%2B)%20%7B%20%20i%2B%2B%3B%20%7D%20return%20i%3B%20%7D)

In other languages, there is no recursion, and you need to use a workaround by adding nested levels "manually". In your examples, you have 2 levels.

Thus, in Python, it will look like:

```
function\s[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\(\)(?:\s?{(?:[^{}]*(?:\s*{[^{}]*}[^{}]*)*})*)
```

See [Python demo](https://regex101.com/r/aO7mL4/2) (also works in JavaScript

In Java, you will need to escape `{`:

```
function\s[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\(\)(?:\s?\{(?:[^\{}]*(?:\s*\{[^{}]*}[^{}]*)*})*)
```

[image]